# route a document or not based on a condition for calendar entry

Tags: workflow, calendar, conditional

If a calendar entry is vacation I want it to route for approval else anything else I want it to auto approve and not route and automatically add it to the calendar  Im new to sharepoint and tried adding it to the approval workflow but cant get it to not route every thing.
thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a SharePoint Designer Workflow.

There you can have `if..else` condition. In this condition you can check `if CurrentItem:Type is equal to Vacation`, if Yes then use action `Start Approval Process`.

Then. `Stop Workflow`

Comment: Thank you.  I can get the approval to work.  It is the items that I want to by-pass the approval I can't get it to work.  No matter what entry I pick from the list (out-of-office, jury duty, etc) it still sends it for approval with the approval workflow process.  I have tried if CurrentItem is not equal to vacation but am not having any luck.  I am using the out-of-the-box approval workflow and trying in SharePoint Designer to only route vacation, all other items on the list should automatically be set to approved and not route.  thanks

Comment: You cant have two approval workflows on the same library. Can you post a screenshot of your Designer Workflow.

Comment: This is the standard workflow for approval.  I am not trying to have two workflows but one which is conditional.  If I pick out-of-office, jury duty, etc (anything but vacation) it automatically gets approved but if I pick vacation then it routes for approval.  There should be a way to add it to the standard workflow but I must not be adding the right code.

Comment: The standard workflow is: 
Change behavior of overall task
When the Task Process Starts
Run these actions immediately after the main workflow reaches this task process
If Day equals Parameter: Duration Units
 Set Variable: DurationUnitsforEmail to day(s)
Else if Week equals Parameter: Duration Units
 Set Variable: DurationUnitsforEmail to week(s)
Else
 Set Variable: DurationUnitsforEmail to month(s)

Comment: If Workflow Context:Association: Start on Item Change equals No
 If Workflow Context:Association: Start to Approve Major Version equals Yes
 or Parameter: Enable Content Approval equals Yes

Comment: Set content approval of item that the task process is running on to Pending (run as the workflow author)
then Set Variable: IsItemApproved to No
then Set Variable: IsItemDeleted to No
If Parameter: Duration Per Task is greater than 0
 Set Variable: DurationDescription to Each person will get [%Parameter: Duration Per Task%] [%Variable: DurationUnitsforEmail%]
If Parameter: Due Date for All Tasks is less than or equal to 12/31/1899 7:00:00 PM
 Set Variable: InitialDueDate to None
Else
 Set Variable: InitialDueDate to [%Parameter: Due Date for All Tasks%] [%Parameter: Due Date for All Tasks%]

Comment: then Email Workflow Context:Initiator
then Log [%Task Process:Process Name%] was started.  Participants:[%Task Process:Participant List%] to the workflow history list
If Task Process:Item URL (UAG) is not empty value
 Set Variable: InternetLink to (Click <a href="[%Task Process:Item URL (UAG)%]”>here</a> to access this item from the internet.
then Set Variable: CompletionMailTitle to [%Task Process:Process Name%] has completed on [%Task Process:Item Title (Unencoded)%].When the task process is running
Run these actions before the task process has assigned its first task:

Comment: The following actions will run in parallel:
Step: When the Item is Deleted
The following actions will run n sequence:
 Wait for deletion of item that the task process is running on
 Set Variable: IsItemDeleted to Yes
 Set Variable: CompletionReason to [%Task Process:Process Name%] has ended because the item that the approval process s running on was deleted.
 then End Task Process